# Want to replace Sass with Lucius or Cassius but running into problems

Tags: haskell, yesod

I want to replace my sass (scss format) files with Lucius or Cassius but I'm running into problems.

I prefer the whitespace sensitive Cassius but it has less features than Lucius.  There doesn't appear to be mixin support for Cassius.  It's only in Lucius.

The mixin support in Lucius has less features than in Sass.  With sass, mixins are allowed to have attributes and selectors.  It's basically a replace macro with optional substitution.  With Lucius, I can only use attributes.  The other selectors are silently ignored.

This is legal in Sass:

```rb
@mixin addMarkup {
    color: #FF00CC;
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        @include modifyParent;
    }
}

@mixin modifyParent {
    &.some-class { float: right };
}

body {
    @include addMarkup;
}
```

which translates to:

```
body { color: #FF00CC; }
body a { text-decoration: none; }
body a.some-class { float: right; }
```

Is there an easy way to replace this syntax with Lucius?  Lucius can handle the first line of the first mixin but it silently ignores the other lines.  In the second mixin, I don't see an easy way to replace '&' which refers to the parent selector so you can reuse attributes across selectors.

I tried this in Lucius

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
import Text.Lucius
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as TLIO
renderer = undefined
addMarkup =
    [luciusMarkup|
        color: #FF00CC;
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            ^{modifyParent}
        }
    |]

modifyParent =
    [luciusMixin|
        .some-class {
            float: right;
        }
    |]

myCss =
    [lucius|
        body {
            ^{addMarkup}
        }
    |]

main = TLIO.putStrLn $ renderCss $ myCSS renderer
```

But it only displays

```
body{color:#FF00CC}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Lucius, a set of CSS properties can be created as a mixin, and reused in multiple declarations. So, when you want to reuse some property, I would do like this:

- Group a set of properties that are going to be re-used. Create them as mixins using `luciusMixin`.
- Add the mixins in the appropriate place where it is required in the `lucius` quasiqouter.

This code will produce your required CSS.

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
import Text.Lucius
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as TLIO

renderer = undefined

colorMixin = [luciusMixin|
              color: #FF00CC;
|]

anchorMixin = [luciusMixin|
               text-decoration:none;
|]

floatMixin = [luciusMixin|
              float:right;
              |]

myCSS =
    [lucius|
        body {
          ^{colorMixin}
          a {^{anchorMixin}}
          a.some-class { ^{floatMixin}
}
   } |]

main = TLIO.putStrLn $ renderCss $ myCSS renderer
```

Comment: So in other words, no there's no easy way to do the replacement. You basically have to do the transformations SASS does on your own.

Comment: @Cubic Yes, I guess so. But if you are using SAAS, just stick with it. There is no need to convert it back to lucius or Cassius. Just include the CSS generated by it in your Yesod template.